# Alternative to Cover Version visualizer in iTunes 12.6

Tags: itunes, software-recommendation, plugins, lyrics

I need a way to display full screen lyrics in iTunes of the song that is currently playing. Up until now I have used Cover Version, but it [doesn't work anymore](http://www.imagomat.de/coverversion/) since iTunes 12.6:

[image: cover version website screenshot]

Are there any alternatives? I am using a mac :)

**EDIT - 29 June 2017**

Apparently it has been fixed and the plugin works now! Many thanks to the developer :)

Comment: Can you clarify whether you're using a Mac or PC? Or do you need a solution for each?

Comment: @Monomeeth I am using a mac :)

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't seem to make 'Cover version' work anymore. (Macbook Pro 2011 - iTunes 12.6(.1.27). And I liked it so much...

Comment: @Jack-O Actually, the new version works again. Try updating iTunes and downloadng cover version again :)

Answer (score 1):

Cover version works on iTunes! What you should do is to create a new directory `~/Library/iTunes/iTunes Plug-ins` and put the Cover version file in there.

- Quit iTunes
- Go to Finder
- Press Alt (OPTION) while selecting GO in the menu
- Go to Library
- Create `iTunes` directoy if it doesn't exist yet
- Go into iTunes directory and create `iTunes Plug-ins`
- Copy Cover Version in there and start iTunes
- Now you can select Cover Version again (CMD +T)

I hope this will work for you ... I works for me in iTunes 12.7.2.58

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I knew how to install it. The issue was that for a period of time the plugin did not work anymore. Since 29 June 2017, it works again correctly :)

Comment: As of this posting dated 12/19/2018 even after trashing and re-creating an iTunes plug-in folder and re-copying the newest version of cover version into it, iTunes does not recognize the third-party plug-in. I think it's been “cooked” - Tim Cooked, that is…

Answer (score 0):

iTunes has its own lyrics display, but it's rubbish...

click the 'Up Next/History tab towards the right on the top of iTunes screen, and you get a Lyrics box as well. You get a drop=down showing the track artwork and the lyrics.

But you can't chose a font nor enlarge the text, and if there is more text that will fit the screen, the lyrics don't scroll down as the track plays, unlike old Cover Version plugin, which was brilliant. :-(